# Visual Studio gitignore .props files

Tags: git, visual-studio

Im developing project on three computers. 3rd party libraries are in different paths. For each lib i configured one .props file in property manager. If I commit .props files with my project every pull will override settings on other machines. If not, project will load with error due to missing .props files. How should I manage my project correctly?

@EDIT
jessehouwing - your solution with enviroment variables was that what I was looking for. For each library I made LIB_XXX_YYY variable pointing to lib root. Now I can make .props files and just set these variables in system. Thank You.

Comment: Could you put the actual path in an environment variable? Or detect the location from the registry?

Comment: Or create a `directory.build.props` file and keep it in the parent folder of the repository.